# I have written a function and am trying to pass it through lapply to run for each row in the data frame

Tags: r, lapply

My code is below

```
    myfunction = function (D)
{

  if( unique( commonData[ , FLAG] ) == "Yes" )
  {
    D[,'YD_Yes'][rownum ] <- commonData[commonData[ , FLAG ] == "Yes", "STRS" ] ;
    D[,'PD_Yes'][ rownum ] <- commonData[ commonData[ , FLAG ] == "Yes", "VAL" ];
  }  else if (unique(commonData[, FLAG]) == "No")
  {
    D[,'YD_Pure_Wasted'][[ rownum ]] <- commonData[commonData[ , FLAG ] == "Pure_No", "STRS" ] ;
    D[,'PD_Pure_Wasted'][[ rownum ]] <- commonData[commonData[ , FLAG ] == "Pure_No", "VAL" ] ;
  } else {
   D[,'YD_Repeated_Wasted'][[ rownum ]] <- commonData[commonData[ , FLAG ] == "Repeated_No", "STRS" ] ;
   D[,'PD_Repeated_Wasted'][[ rownum ]] <- commonData[commonData[ , FLAG ] == "Repeated_No", "VAL" ] ;
   }

    temp = lapply(myfunction, mydataframe)
```

I expect the calculation in the function to execute. However the error message is:

```
Error in `[.default`(`*tmp*`, "YD_Yes") : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of data that reproduces this error?

Comment: `lapply` will try to apply the function on each column. Also, the object comes before the function. Try `apply(mydataframe,1,myfunction)`

Comment: `lapply` iterates over vectors not data.frames. Thats why the error say incorrect number of dimensions data.frames have 2 dimensions and vectors only 1. You may want to try `apply(df,1,fxn)` where 1 indicates rowwise as opposed to 2 which is by column see the help for apply with `?apply`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, welcome to SO.

Now, about your question: as 'Rohit' said, lapply isn't the correct approach to your problem. You should use apply instead.

But there is another problem in your code (not exactly a problem, but a code bad smell), they're the variables you are using in your function: rownum, commonData and FLAG. They're out scope variables and it's hard to track them.

So first declare them in your function:

```
myFunction = function(D, rownum, commonData, FLAG) {
    # your function code
}
```

And them use apply to iterate each row in "myFunction":

```
apply(D, 1, rownum, commonData, FLAG)
```

The first apply param is the data to be iterated (the fist function argument) and the last 3 params are the rest of the function arguments.

But remember: Before to make a question, try to create a reproducible example so we can help you faster.